# EF Core 5 updates unchanged entities and properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following code-first models:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Field : BaseEntity
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Component Component { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public Field() { }
    
    public Field(string value, Component component, string status = null)
    {
        Value = value;
        Component = component;
        Status = status;
    }
}

public class Component : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SmartObject")]
    public int? SmartObjectId { get; set; }
    public Component SmartObject { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Component Parent { get; set; }
    public ComponentType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    public IList<QueryComponent> Queries { get; set; }
    public IList<ReportComponent> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

and the following logic (here written in pseudo-code, possible that I missed something, in which case - apologies):

```
public class SampleClass
{
     IFieldRepository _fieldRepository;

     public SampleClass(IFieldRepository fieldRepository)
     {
          _fieldRepository = fieldRepository;
     }

     public void UpdateStatus()
     {
         var fieldList = _fieldRepository.GetById(3);
         
        foreach (var item in updateFVList_Formatted)
        {
             item.Status = "new";
             _fieldRepository.DisableChange(item);
        }
     }
}

public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    internal ApplicationDBContext _context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> _entity;

    public BaseRepository(ApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entity = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void GetById(int ID)
    {
        return _entity.Where(x => x.Id == ID).ToList();
    }

    public void DisableChange(Field field)
    {
        _context.Entry(field).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        _context.Entry(field.Component).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}
```

Here the "UpdateStatus" method is being called.

The issue I have and the reason for the "DisableChange" method is that EF Core decides that the "Component" property has been changed or something and when changes are saved, no matter what I do that has nothing to do with "Component" - EF Core updates the "Component" table in the database and sets its "ParentId" property to `NULL`, along with any other actual changes.

So for example with the following pseudo code, if the call to "DisableChanges" is omitted and I just call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, EF Core updates the entries in the "Field" table AND the "ParentId" column of the "Component" table.

I tried telling EF Core "Component" is not changed via the "DisableChange" method but all that did was omit the update clause for the entries in the "Field" table. Resulting in a single `UPDATE` to the "Component" table.

I can't figure out why this is happening and how to prevent it. I want EF Core to ONLY update the "Field" items that I actually change.